# Perl: retrieve output from process in IPC::Run if it dies

Tags: perl, error-handling

I have been running some commands with the [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) module and everything is fine, except that I can't access the output (STDOUT, STDERR), the process produced and were redirected into variables. Is there a way to retrieve those in the error handling?

```
@commands = ();
foreach my $id (1..3) {
  push @commands, ["perl", "script" . $id . ".pl"];
}

foreach my $cmd (@commands) {
  my $out = "";
  my $err = "";
  my $h = harness $cmd, \undef, \$out, \$err, timeout(12,exception => {name => 'timeout'});
  eval {
    run $h;
  };

  if ($@) {
    my $err_msg = $@; # save in case another error happens
    print "$out\n";
    print "$err\n";
    $h->kill_kill;
  }
}
```

I don't need any input for now, I just need to execute it and get the output.

**EDIT**
I have been testing it with running perl scripts which look like this:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  sleep 1;
  print "Hello from script 1 " . localtime() . "\n";
}
```

I have 3 such scripts with different times and the 3rd takes 20 seconds to complete, which is more than the 12 I have in the timer.

Comment: Do you mean `$out` and `$err`? Those should be available if `$cmd` produced any output before the timeout. Are you sure the command timed out? Note: Your script does not print anything unless there is a timeout.

Comment: Yes, I mean those. Well, I didn't put the whole code there, this is just the main part. I am running 3 scripts which print sth and go to sleep and I set one of them to go for longer than the timer is going. The first 2 are printed out fine, but the 3rd is caught by the timer and exits. But the output isn't available...
I am using it with a Fork Manager, so I didn't write the whole thing, since it could get messy.

Comment: Ok. Could you provide an example of the third script, so we can try reproduce?

Comment: if you aren't seeing any output from the 3rd script, it is possibly being buffered.  do you get the output when it *doesn't* time out?

Comment: @HåkonHægland I have updated it.

Comment: @ysth I have tried to put the timer up and the script is still showing up.
One solution is to save those things in a file, but I want to bypass that if possible, bcs there will be a lot of sciprts running and I would need to manage the temporary files around. And it would probably be slower.

Comment: @HeatTheIce Thanks for the update. Try to put `STDOUT->autoflush(1)` at the beginning of the script. According to [`perlvar`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) : *"STDOUT will typically be line buffered if output is to the terminal and block buffered otherwise"*

Comment: @HeatTheIce: Please don't use "text speak" in your posts on *Stack Overflow*. The site is not a forum, but is intended to form a repository of the most valuable solutions to programming problems, and deserves rather more dignity. Furthermore, your audience is an international one and you cannot assume that the abbreviations that you choose to use can be understood universally. I am English, and I found it very frustrating to have to google `sth` before I could read your comment. Your efforts to save yourself a tiny amount of typing have cost me substantially more time to interpret your words.

Comment: I recommend that you use `my @commands = map [ "perl", "script$_.pl" ], 1 .. 3` instead of the first `for` loop.

Comment: *"I am using it with a Fork Manager"* Do you mean `Parallel::ForkManager`?

Comment: @Borodin sorry for they of writing. I'm used to write certain things in a way and forget to correct it if I am writing a post or comment.
As for the for loop, this is only an example which I use for debug, because later I will have to execute shell scripts or commands.
As for the Fork Manager you are right, I am using it. But I tried to use the script above and the problem still exists, so I excluded it from causing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by @ysth, the reason you do not get any output, is that the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` of the process corresponding to the command `$cmd`, is not line buffered, but rather block buffered. So all output is collected in a buffer which is not shown (printed) until the buffer is full or it is explicitly flushed. However, when your command times out, all the output is still in the buffer and has not yet been flushed and hence collected into the variable `$out` in the parent process (script).

Also note that since your `$cmd` script is a Perl script, this behavior is documented in [`perlvar`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> **$|**
>
> If set to nonzero, forces a flush right away and after every write
>   or print on the currently selected output channel. Default is 0
>   (regardless of whether the channel is really buffered by the system or
>   not; $| tells you only whether you've asked Perl explicitly to flush
>   after each write). **STDOUT will typically be line buffered if output is
>   to the terminal and block buffered otherwise**.

The problem (that the program is not connected to a terminal or a tty) is also noted in the documentation page for [`IPC::Run`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) :

> Interactive applications are usually optimized for human use. This can
>   help or hinder trying to interact with them through modules like
>   IPC::Run. Frequently, programs alter their behavior when they detect
>   that stdin, stdout, or stderr are not connected to a tty, assuming
>   that they are being run in batch mode. Whether this helps or hurts
>   depends on which optimizations change. And there's often no way of
>   telling what a program does in these areas other than trial and error
>   and occasionally, reading the source. This includes different versions
>   and implementations of the same program.

The documentation also lists a set of possible workarounds, including using [pseudo terminals](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run#PSEUDO-TERMINALS).

One solution for your specific case is then to explicitly make `STDOUT` line buffered at the beginning of your script:

```
STDOUT->autoflush(1);  # Make STDOUT line buffered
# Alternatively use: $| = 1; 
for (my $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  sleep 1;
  print "Hello from script 1 " . localtime() . "\n";
}
```

**Edit**:

If you cannot modify the scripts you are running for some reason, you could try connect the script to a pseudo terminal. So instead of inserting statements like `STDOUT->autoflush(1)` in the source code of the script, you can fool the script to believe it is connected to a terminal, and hence that it should use line buffering. For your case, we just add a `>pty>` argument before the `\$out` argument in the call to `harness`:

```
my $h = harness $cmd, \undef, '>pty>', \$out,
  timeout(12, exception => {name => 'timeout'});
eval {
    run $h;
};
```

Comment: Using your solution indeed solved my problem. But I will still have a problem, since I wont be using only perl scripts in the future. Is there maybe an other module which will save the output directly to a handler or similar? I have tried using an IO::Handler, but I didn't get it to work...

Comment: Maybe you could also try fool the scripts you are running to believe it is connected to a real tty by using pseudo terminals as described in the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run#PSEUDO-TERMINALS)

Comment: Nit: `print "..."` technically prints to the handle returned by `select()`, so `select()->autoflush(1);` would make more sense than `STDOUT->autoflush(1);`. Of course, `select()->autoflush(1);` can also be written as `$| = 1;`.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for the comment! This is good to know, but since it should (?) be quite clear from script of the OP, that it is trying to output to STDOUT (so the selected handle is indeed STDOUT for their case), I am not updating my answer with the more "correct" approach as you suggested. I think it contains enough details as it is, and I would like to avoid further confusions/distractions, but you can leave the comment as it is if it is OK?

Comment: Yup. Like I said, it was just a nit.

Comment: Okay, that connection with a tty really worked. Now I will just have to see how many scripts I can run at the same time, because it could go over 45 scripts running at the same time. But thank you for the solution!