# Implementation of timeout in perl

Tags: shell, perl, timeout, settimeout

In the following perl script, i intend to timeout the execution of script `child_script.pl` if it goes beyond 1 hour. However, the logic doesn't seem to be working as the script is still running after the specified time limit.

Any guesses what am I doing wrong here?

I'm referring to follwing documentation for implementing the timeout in perl:
https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/cook/ch16_22.htm

It works fine for a standalone command. Is it possible that `system` command has an issue ?

**MY_CODE** (`parent_script.pl`)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $sys_cmd = " perl child_script.pl 2>&1 | tee logfile.txt \n";

print "INFO: Enter alarm..\n";
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm clock restart" };
    alarm 3600;                   # schedule alarm in 1 hours
    eval {
            print "INFO: Run script.. \n";
            system ($sys_cmd);
    };
    alarm 0;                    # cancel the alarm
};
alarm 0;                        # race condition protection
die if $@ && $@ !~ /alarm clock restart/; # reraise
print "INFO: Exit alarm..\n";
```

Comment: See also [Timeout for launching a bash command in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50040421/2173773), [Perl: retrieve output from process in IPC::Run if it dies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50392512/2173773), and [Perl timeout command in windows and linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53770493/2173773) for alternative approaches using among others [`IPC::Run`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run)

Answer (score 2):

You don't time out the script which you have started; you set the alarm for the current (parent) script. You would have to kill the child process (the one you have started using `system`) from your alarm-`sub`.

EDIT:

If you have `/usr/bin/timeout` (as it would be the case if you are running on Linux), it would perhaps be more convenient to use this command for handling the timeout, instead of re-implementing the logic in Perl.

Comment: Hey user1934428, Sorry I couldn't get your point. I dont intend to kill the parent_script.pl script. I want to kill the child_script.pl if it continues to run after 1 hour. I have updated the names of script in the description for better clarity. Thanks!

Comment: But the alarm signal goes to the parent script, not the child.

Comment: @Yash : I know that you want to; but nothing in your code is killing the child script.

Comment: @Yash : Killing your child can be done using the [kill](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html) function of Perl, and there is no _kill_ in your code.

Comment: Thanks, let me check if `kill` helps.

Answer (score 1):

The `SIGALRM` signal may or may not be sent while your `system` call is running, so `alarm` may be flaky. This is a good use case for [the poor man's alarm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8452732/168657).

```
my $sys_cmd = "perl child_script.pl 2>&1 | tee logfile.txt";
# step 1. Start your long running command and capture it's process id
my $pid = fork();
if ($pid == 0) {
    exec($sys_cmd);
}
# step 2. Start another subprocess for the poor man's alarm.
my $time = 3600;
if (fork() == 0) {
    exec("$^X","-e","sleep 1,kill(0,$pid)||exit for 1..$time;kill -9,$pid");
}
# step 3. wait for first process to finish or be killed
my $c = waitpid $pid, 0;
if ($c & 128 == 9) {
    print "Process timed out and was killed by the poor man's alarm\n";
} else {
    print "Process finished without timing out.\n";
}
```

The poor man's alarm runs in a separate process with two parameters: a `$pid` to monitor and a `$time` to wait. It periodically checks to see if the process being monitored is still alive. If the process is no longer alive, then the poor man's alarm also exits without doing anything. After `$time` seconds have passed, and the monitored process is still hanging around, the poor man's alarm sends a kill signal to the process, which should terminate it.

Comment: Are we sure that `my $time = 3600` is in seconds. I ran this piece of code with `$time = 600` but it keeps on running well beyond 10 mins.